Existence of eigenstates in the context of continuous energies in the Lippmann-Schwinger equation
In the book QFT by Schwartz, in section 4.1 "Lippmann-Schwinger equation", he says that:

If we write Hamiltonian as $H=H_0+V$ and the energies are continuous, and we have eigenstate of $H_0$:
$$H_0|\phi\rangle =E|\phi\rangle\tag{4.2}$$
then we are able to find an eigenstate of $H$ with same energy:$$H|\psi\rangle =E|\psi\rangle.\tag{4.3}$$

My question is, why we can find such an eigenstate? And what has it to do with the continuity of energies?

You usually assume that the continuous spectra of $H_0$ and $H$ coincide. Any decent book on scattering theory should discuss this (and to what extend this holds, and how to formulate this precisely/rigorously in mathematical terms).

Can you give me an example of such discussion? I read mainly only the book by Schwartz, and he discusses this issue in a very rough manner, without offering any explanations.

The one by Newton, or the one by Taylor, or the relevant sections in Amrein. Also the book by Böhm and the one by Merzbacher contains nice discussions, IIRC.
